# i have a method to return a hashMap,

Tags: hashmap

i called the method in the main method, but the problem is how to manuplate the values individually in the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Map<Integer, Integer> re = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    System.out.print(methodReturningTwoInts());

    Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> keySet = re.entrySet();
    keySet.getClass();

    for(Integer j=0; j <3;j++){
        if(methodReturningTwoInts().containsKey(1)){
        re.put((j+1), methodReturningTwoInts().getValues);
        }
    }
}
public static Map<Integer, Integer> methodReturningTwoInts()

{

    Integer a = 3;

    Integer b = 6;

    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    result.put(1, a);

    result.put(2, b);

    return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @shinjw want to be adding the value of the hashmap in method to the hashmap in the main method

Comment: Show your console outputs.

Comment: @shinjw this line shows  **methodReturningTwoInts().getValues** red which means it will not run

Answer (score 0):

getValues is not a valid method for maps. You can use methodReturningTwoInts().get(key) to get your corresponding value. In your case your key is (j + 1).

`re.put((j+1), methodReturningTwoInts().get(j+1));`